# Shareing AppConfigurations.json through two projects

Tags: c#, configuration, asp.net-core-2.0

I have the following project structure in a Visual-Studio Solution. There are two project, one of them is a .net-core 2.0 console application and the other one is a .net-core 2.0 mvc application. You can see the correct solution structure in the picture below.

[image]

How you can see, there is in the Project DT_TestSystem a file which is called SharedAppConfiguration.json, which holds the basic settings for both projects and of course it is very easy to access this file in the project DT_TestSystem. By the following code:

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("SharedAppConfiguration.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }
```

After that i do some dependency injection in the project DT_TestSystem and i can use the informations of the file. The project DT_TestSystem will publish it's files after compilation to bin\Release\netcoreapp2.0\publish.

**But now i have the problem, that i also wanna access the SharedAppConfiguration.json by the DataCollector Project. But they don't share this files. How can i access the file or how can i share the "SharedAppConfigurations.json".**

There is a possibility to link an existing item as a link like the picture below. But what happens and how i have to publish the solution if i'm using this? And how can i use it in the Data Collector Project? The file is not really there...
[image]

I tried in the DataCollector Project something like that. But this needs a hard coded path right? Is there a solution for a question like this?

```
Console.WriteLine("Load Shared Configuration...");
        var myBasePath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
        var settingPath = Path.Combine(myBasePath,"NO IDEA WHAT TO DO...");
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(settingPath)
            .AddJsonFile("SharedAppConfiguration.json",optional:false, reloadOnChange: true);
        Configuration = builder.Build();
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: In production, you can employ environment variables or something like Azure Key Vault to "share" settings. Trying to share physical JSON files is a very brittle approach, and unnecessary given that there's far better ways to have a distributed config.

Comment: @ChrisPratt how can i implement a better distributed config file? i can't use azure key vault, because i would like to publish the solution on IIS

Comment: One has nothing to do with the other. You can use Azure Key Vault, even if your app isn't hosted in Azure. However, like I said, there's also environment variables. Outside of that, you're reliant on third-party integrations or rolling your own config providers, but virtually any data stored can be used as a config provider: Redis, SQL Server, whatever. You just need to find or create the appropriate provider.

Comment: @ChrisPratt do you have a code sample for sharing configurations between projects?

Comment: No, because it's nothing special. The secret sauce is in using a distributed *store*. Each project just pulls its config from there using an appropriate config provider, just like `AddJsonFile`, only with your config provider that hits the distributed store.

Comment: @ChrisPratt ok i think i have to tell you some more. The two projects in the solution are working hand in hand. The data collector project is a long running job (never ever ends) which writes in the same database which is also the DT_TestSystem is using. In the project DT_TestSystem i can configure the Database-Connection-String by Runtime, which is necessary for both projects. In this case there is no possibility to use a SQL server to share this information, because before i can do this - i have to exchange the database-connection-string

Comment: Yes, that in particular is a chicken-egg problem, but that's where other options come in: set the connection string in an environment variable, set it in Azure Key Vault, or a Redis instance. FWIW, you should never store connection strings in a JSON file *anyways* because they're unencrypted plaintext - you'll leak your credentials. It also means that you'll end up committing your credentials into source control, making them even more vulnerable.